Installed Ubuntu on MacBook, Can’t Access macOS and Data
I installed Ubuntu on my MacBook, and now I can’t access my macOS or my data. In Disk Utility, I can’t see the macOS partition, and I am unable to access my files. My main goal is to remove Ubuntu and recover macOS along with all my data.
How can I restore macOS and my data without losing anything? Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Restoring data is very hard without a backup.

Not really a Ubuntu question but more MacOS focused. However, you might find this Apple Communuty post helpful in the meantime.
